# What can I do when iTunes multiplies albums?

Tags: itunes, music

For as long as I can remember, iTunes has had bugs that will split the songs of an album into multiple albums with the same name when one edits the album name. This happens infrequently and seemingly randomly, and could usually be mitigated by selecting the offending tracks, renaming the album and then renaming it back to the correct title. But now I have this:
[image]

And the trick does not work. Changing the album title actually renames it but does nothing to join the fragments. Oddly, renaming the artist does rename the artist, but the change does not show in the artist bar on the left. Does anyone have the same experience and suggestions as to what to do?

- I could remove and re-add the songs, but I'd rather not have to re-add them to every playlist and lose play count and stuff
- Is it possible to edit the itunes database directly somehow?

**iTunes version 12**

Comment: This is usually just a naming issue.  Have you checked the 'Sorting' tab, where 'sort as' mainly is the reason why parts of an album don't show as such.  Also with multiple album artists, you should mark the album as compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have this issue, and I can fix it by selecting all of the offending tracks (e.g. the entire album) using Option + click, right clicking and changing the "Album Artist" to something random (I usually use "asdf") and then doing to same thing to change it to the correct Album Artist. Doing this forces iTunes to re-index the album and put the parts together.

If this does not fix it, then look for any other data that should match between all the tracks but doesn't. iTunes is splitting the album because of one of the tags, and by setting the offending tag to the same on all of the songs it forces iTunes to put it together.

Comment: It is interesting that now renaming the album artists now actually works, but didn't when I initially asked the questions. Maybe an intermediate update fixed some issue.

Comment: @Are you sure you were selecting all the parts of the album at the same time? You must for it to work.

Comment: Yes of course, it would be nonsensical otherwise. The interesting thing was, that in the album view, the album appeared only once, but in the artist view several times, despite the fact that artist and album artist fields where identical (iTunes shows it if field content is inhomogenous).

Comment: Weird. I have actually experienced similar bizarreness with iTunes tagging/indexing before. iTunes does do weird things occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

As willem.hill stated correctly: the best way in approaching this issue, is to change all tracks of the album in question in one go.

1. Use `Show items in list, grid or with Cover Flow` mode
2. Mark the first track, hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, the click the last track, then hit <kbd></kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> > which opens `Multipe Item Information` preferences window
3. Now rename the complete album in one go, by putting in all the information.

[image]